# Is pytesseract safe to use with confidential images?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am working on a project for my company which tries to read scanned pdfs and classify them depending on their contents.

After doing some research online, the easiest way to solve this seems to be by using a Python Library called [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract).

My question is: Is this library safe to use with images containing confidential customer data? Do the images/the extracted text get saved in some server?

I found this [link](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/pytesseract) which suggests that it is. But I am lacking understandment of what exactly happens '*behind the scenes*' everytime I read an image with the module.

Thanks in advance for any help!